# text string output stops after first space, js/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I apologize in advance, this is the first Stack Overflow question I've posted. I was tasked with creating a new ADA compliant website for my school district's technology helpdesk. I started with minimal knowledge of HTML and have been teaching myself through w3cschools. So here's my ordeal:

I need to create a page for all of our pdf and html guides. I'm trying to create a somewhat interactable menu that is very simple and will populate a link array from an onclick event, but the title="" text attribute drops everything after the first space and I've unsuccessfully tried using a replace() method since it's coming from an array and not static text.

I know I'm probably supposed to use an example, but my work day is coming to a close soon and I wanted to get this posted so I just copied a bit of my actual code.

So here's what's happening, in example 1 of var gmaildocAlt the tooltip will drop everything after Google, but will show the entire string properly with example 2. I was hoping to create a form input for the other helpdesk personnel to add links without knowing how to code, but was unable to resolve the issue of example 1 with a

var fix = gmaildocAlt.replace(/ /g, "&nb sp;")

//minus the space

//this also happens to break the entire function if I set it below the rest of the other variables

I'm sure there are a vast number of things I'm doing wrong, but I would really appreciate the smallest tip to make my tooltip display properly without requiring a replace method.

```js
// GMAIL----------------------------
function gmailArray() {
  var gmaildocLink = ['link1', 'link2'];
  var gmaildocTitle = ["title1", "title2"];
  var gmaildocAlt = ["Google Cheat Sheet For Gmail", "Google&nbsp;10-Minute&nbsp;Training&nbsp;For&nbsp;Gmail"];
  var gmailvidLink = [];
  var gmailvidTitle = [];
  var gmailvidAlt = [];
  if (document.getElementById("gmailList").innerHTML == "") {
    for (i = 0; i < gmaildocTitle.length; i++) {
      arrayGmail = "<a href=" + gmaildocLink[i] + " " + "title=" + gmaildocAlt[i] + ">" + gmaildocTitle[i] + "</a>" + "<br>";
      document.getElementById("gmailList").innerHTML += arrayGmail;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < gmailvidTitle.length; i++) {
      arrayGmail1 = "";
      document.getElementById("").innerHTML += arrayGmail1;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("gmailList").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed1">
  <p id="gmail" onclick="gmailArray()" class="gl">Gmail</p>
  <ul id="gmailList"></ul>
  <p id="calendar" onclick="calendarArray()" class="gl">Calendar</p>
  <ul id="calendarList"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building HTML manually with strings can cause issues like this. It's better to build them one step at a time, and let the framework handle quoting and special characters - if you're using jQuery, it could be:

```
var $link = jQuery("<a></a>")
    .attr("href", gmaildocLink[i])
    .attr("title", gmaildocAlt[i])
    .html(gmaildocTitle[i]);
jQuery("#gmailList").append($link).append("<br>");
```

Without jQuery, something like:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", gmaildocLink[i]);
link.setAttribute("title", gmaildocAlt[i]);
link.innerHTML = gmaildocTitle[i];
document.getElementById("gmailList").innerHTML += link.outerHTML + "<br>";
```

If it matters to your audience, `setAttribute` doesn't work in IE7, and you have to access the attributes as properties of the element: `link.href = "something";`.

Comment: I just haven't taught myself jQuery yet. I had to stop working on the site to make everything compliant and then teach myself JavaScript to get back to work creating this page. So I was trying to rush my progress assuming I could just go back later and update the code once I knew more.

Target audience uses Chrome 85% of the time at home, and they all have IE 10+ on district devices.

Comment: My favorite thing about jQuery was the cross-browser compliance - that's much less of an issue now than it used to be since IE11 and Edge are becoming more popular. Chaining things together is still really nice, and there are still plenty of other good reasons to use jQuery, but if you really want to do cool stuff, frameworks like Angular seem to be winning the future of app development over manipulating the DOM directly with jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

If you add ' to either side of the variable strings then it will ensure that the whole value is read as a single string. Initially, it was assuming that the space was exiting the Title attribute.

Hope the below helps!

UPDATE: If you're worried about using apostrophes in the title strings, you can use " by escaping them using a . This forces JS to read it as a character and not as part of the code structure. See the example below.

Thanks for pointing this one out guys! Sloppy code on my part.

```js
// GMAIL----------------------------
function gmailArray() {
  var gmaildocLink = ['link1', 'link2'];
  var gmaildocTitle = ["title1", "title2"];
  var gmaildocAlt = ["Google's Cheat Sheet For Gmail", "Google 10-Minute Training For Gmail"];
  var gmailvidLink = [];
  var gmailvidTitle = [];
  var gmailvidAlt = [];
  if (document.getElementById("gmailList").innerHTML == "") {
    for (i = 0; i < gmaildocTitle.length; i++) {
      var arrayGmail = "<a href=" + gmaildocLink[i] + " title=\"" + gmaildocAlt[i] + "\">" + gmaildocTitle[i] + "</a>" + "<br>";
      document.getElementById("gmailList").innerHTML += arrayGmail;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < gmailvidTitle.length; i++) {
      var arrayGmail1 = "";
      document.getElementById("").innerHTML += arrayGmail1;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("gmailList").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed1">
   <p id="gmail" onclick="gmailArray()" class="gl">Gmail</p>
   <ul id="gmailList"></ul>
   <p id="calendar" onclick="calendarArray()" class="gl">Calendar</p>
   <ul id="calendarList"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning, be sure to define arrayGmail with var

Comment: you should also define `i` variable that you are using in the loop (if not the global `i` will be used which might introduce other problems)

Comment: It'll work until you have a value that has an apostrophe in it, at which point it will break without much help as to why.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and the edit to your own answer. While I will probably use the other suggestion to clean up my code a bit, this will go a long way when I create other unmanageable objects!

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) in honesty, you're better off using JQuery, at least in my opinion. Saves a lot of keystrokes!